# Escape " (doublequote) in @Value property name

Tags: java, spring

I have the following structure for a property:

```
my {
    property {
        item {
            "1" {
                value="some value"
            }
            "2" {
                value="another value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do you refer to a property called "1" using the `@Value` annotation?

The example I have doesn't work. I tried the following options:

```
@Bean(name = "myProperty")
public String myProperty(@Value("${my.property.item.\"1\".value}") String myProperty) {
    return myProperty;
}

@Bean(name = "myProperty")
public String myProperty(@Value("${my.property.item.'1'.value}") String myProperty) {
    return myProperty;
}

@Bean(name = "myProperty")
public String myProperty(@Value("${my.property.item.1.value}") String myProperty) {
    return myProperty;
}
```

None of which work.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I don't know about spring, but maybe try this to escape `"`: `@Value("${my.property.item.\\\"1\\\".value}")`

Comment: Are these properties in a `.properties` file ? AFAIK the `@Value` is to get the values from your `application.properties`, so your item should look like this 
```my.property.item.1.value=Some stuff```

Comment: @Value can also read environment variables.... but either way, there is no practical reason for quotes to be in the property name

Answer (score 1):

Best way to fix that, is to just rename the properties, since java doesn't like when there are quotes inside of names.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so Java definitely doesn't like the quotes in the name so my solution has instead (in my case) been to refer to the property using an alias although I realise this isn't apparent in the small example I gave (I didn't want to overcomplicate it).

In my example there's a set of property files that are imported into a Spring `application.conf` file.

Inside this `application.conf` file I put the following property:

```
myProperty.value=true
```

This overrides the other property

Then inside my original property file I simply refer to it.

```
my {
    property {
        item {
            "1" {
                value=${myProperty.value}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That means when I bind the property in a `*Config.java` file I can do:

```
@Bean(name = "myProperty")
public String myProperty(@Value("${myProperty.value}") String myProperty) 
{
    return myProperty;
}
```

Hope this helps people.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to have quotes in the property name? I can't think of any valid reason

Comment: @RobOnRob Can't talk about specifics. I didn't write the code. It's a government system and core functionality so I needed a work around that involves not changing names. Legacy so not as many tests as I'd like.

Basically the least I have to do to upset the applecart for reasonable gains the better.